# I want to pass the my query output into jQuery chart js using Laravel 7

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, charts

I want to show each month's registered student count in the line chart. I got the result from the query but I can't understand how to pass the value in the line chart js file. Please help to fix this issue. I attached the codes and the screenshots for my output.

I want to pass the query output **dat**a count value into jQuery  **data: [0, 4, 9, 18, 21, 34, 20, 35, 45, 53, 49, 60],**

**app.js**

```
(function ($) {
  "use strict"; // Chart
  if ($('#report-line-chart').length) {
    var ctx = $('#report-line-chart')[0].getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of total',
          data: [0, 4, 9, 18, 21, 34, 20, 35, 45, 53, 49, 60],
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: '#3160D8',
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          pointBorderColor: 'transparent'
        }]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              fontSize: '12',
              fontColor: '#777777'
            },
            gridLines: {
              display: false
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              fontSize: '12',
              fontColor: '#777777',
              callback: function callback(value, index, values) {
                return value;
              }
            },
            gridLines: {
              color: '#D8D8D8',
              zeroLineColor: '#D8D8D8',
              borderDash: [2, 2],
              zeroLineBorderDash: [2, 2],
              drawBorder: false
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  })($s);
```

**My controller query**

```
<?php
$arr["eachMonthRegister"] = DB::table('students')->select(DB::raw('count(id) as `data`'),  DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year, MONTH(created_at) month'))
        ->groupby('year','month')
        ->get();

        return view('home')->with($arr);
?>
```

**My query output**

[image]

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems. Try to improve that. Use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments. Don't use too much **bold** font. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually You are doing it right, but i added some parts to your code.

**- Controller**

```
$result = DB::table('students')->select(DB::raw('count(id) as `data`'),  
DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year, MONTH(created_at) month'))
    ->groupby('year','month')
    ->orderby('month) // I added this line
    ->get();

$output = [];
    
foreach ($result as $entry) {
    if (isset($output[$entry->month]))
        $output[$entry->month] += $entry->data;
    else
        $output[$entry->month] = $entry->data;
}
$lineChartData= array_values($output);
return view('home')->with($lineChartData);

 // $lineChartData will be like below
 // [0, 4, 9, 18, 21, ...]
```

**- home.blade**

```
<script>
    var lineChartData = @json($lineChartData)
    // [0, 4, 9, 18, 21, ...]
</script>
```

**- app.js**

```
 .
 ..
 ...
 datasets: [{
      label: '# of total',
      data: lineChartData,
```

---

**Another Note:** it seems that you do not need `year` returned from DB. if it is so you can change codes like below and improve performance and speed of your code:

**- Controller**

```
$result = DB::table('students')->select(DB::raw('count(id) as `data`'),  
DB::raw(MONTH(created_at) month'))
    ->groupby('month')
    ->orderby('month)
    ->get();


// same as top codes
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much this one is working perfectly :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue JUST LIKE YOU have and solved yesterday! So, I am telling my full approach for you and anyone else facing this problem.

### Problem 1:

Like you, I also thought about groupBy with `year` and `month` but after getting the output of the query, I figured out that it's not groupBy which can solve our issue. Because, groupBy will only group/collect/count the values for the same month or year. So, we won't get straight 12 values like in a year for each month (Specially for the month which has no value won't give us 0 but we need 0 for our case). So, I had to create my own query like below. It will give you straight 12 values for each 12 month for the current year!:

### Solution Query:

```php
$months = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12'];
$group_by_month = [];

// note that this foreach() will loop through exactly 12 times!
foreach($months as $key => $month){
    $group_by_month[$key] = DB::table('students')
                ->whereBetween('created_at',[date('Y').'-'.$month.'-01',date('Y').'-'.$month.'-31'])
                ->get()
                ->count();
}

$data['group_by_month_this_year'] = $group_by_month;

return view('home',$data); // in your home you can access $group_by_month_this_year
```

### Problem 2:

The second problem I faced (probably you also will) is that the data returned was indexed array but we need array without index so `json_encode` will help, for @directive the short form is `@json`. So, add this line in your data:

```js
data: @json($group_by_month_this_year)
```

***Note:*** For my case, I needed the data for `current and previous year`, so I added the code of `current year` for you. If you want to do it from `start to end` then let me know, I will try to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may implement line chart using the following ways.

I am going to use simple line chart from next URL to reduce code.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html

#### 1. Laravel /routes/web.php and welcome.blade.php (template)

**PHP will parse blade template file and convert it as HTML.**

routes/web.php

```php
...
Route::get('/', function () {
    $items = DB::table('students')
    ->select(DB::raw("count(id) as `data`, year || '-' || month as month"))
    ->groupBy('year','month')
    ->get();
    $values = $items->pluck('data'); // ["6","6","6","6","12"]
    $months = $items->pluck('month'); // ["2015-10","2015-11","2015-12","2016-1","2016-10"]  
    return view('welcome', ['values'=> $values, 'months' => $months]);
});
```

resources/views/welcome.blade.php

```html
...
<head>
...
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="antialiased">
    <div>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
...
    <script>
    var values = {!! json_encode($values) !!};
    var labels = {!! json_encode($months) !!};
    console.log("this is from welcome.blade.php",values,labels);
    const data = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: values,
        }]
    };  
    const config = {
        type: 'line',
        data,
        options: {}
    };    

    var myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
    );    

    </script>   
</body>
```

**php will parse this blade template and convert next code**

```
var values = {!! json_encode($values) !!};
var labels = {!! json_encode($months) !!};
```

**to**

```
var values = ["6","6","6","6","12"];
var labels = ["2015-10","2015-11","2015-12","2016-1","2016-10"];
```

#### 2. Laravel /routes/web.php and /public/js/custom.js ajax request

**Browser will get HTML and then calling AJAX. After callback, chart js will be rendered with labels and values.**

routes/web.php

```php
...
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/ajax', function () {    
    $items = DB::table('students')
    ->select(DB::raw("count(id) as `data`, year || '-' || month as month"))
    ->groupBy('year','month')
    ->get();
    $values = $items->pluck('data'); // ["6","6","6","6","12"]
    $months = $items->pluck('month'); // ["2015-10","2015-11","2015-12","2016-1","2016-10"]
    return ['values'=> $values, 'months' => $months];
});
```

resources/views/welcome.blade.php

```html
<head>
...
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>        
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

public/js/custom.js

```js
$.get( "/ajax", function( items ) {
    console.log("this data is from ajax request from custom.js",items);
    const data = {
        labels: items.months,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: items.values,
        }]
    };  
    const config = {
        type: 'line',
        data,
        options: {}
      };    

    var myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
      );    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change your collection to array and only take the values of your collection

```
$array = $collection->toArray();
foreach($array as $a){
    $result[] = $a['data'];
}

return view('your.view', compact('result'));
```

And here's my solution, **avoid external JS file**. Then pass your variable

here's how :

```
<script>

...
datasets: [{
          label: '# of total',
          data: {!! json_encode($result) !!},
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: '#3160D8',
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          pointBorderColor: 'transparent'
        }]
...
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't pass the data well to the view. with() is used to flash data to the session.

Try like this in your Controller:

```
return view('home', ['mydata' => $arr]);
```

And you get it in the view with the variable **$mydata**

You can pass as many variable you want:

```
return view('home', ['mydata' => $arr, 'mydata2' => $arr2]);
```